# KineticJS Kinetic.Shape.drawImage Performance leak

Tags: performance, kineticjs, drawimage

So I have a pretty complex structure. I will try to explain it in a nutshell, just enough to get an idea of the code...

I have an application with contains a few steps:

preload startscreen
build/show startscreen
press start
load the pretty huge app
build the app

The last part is the source of my concerns, since the building of the app can take up to 2 seconds!!

So lets zoom into that part...

What the building part does is create different kind of views. I have a close-up for a leg, head, hands and an overall view. Each view has different layers. Background, foreground, person, items, etc.

So the app contains different views, each views has an own set of layers.

Each layer has its set of images and hitspots. Al of the images and hitspots are added to the layer and events will be bind to the hitspots.

The creation of the views looks like this:

```
    function CreateTopFullTotalView() {
    //layers
    topfullTotalBackground = new SimulationDisplays.Background(_self, View.TopFullTotal);
    topfullTotalBystanders = new SimulationDisplays.Bystanders(_self, View.TopFullTotal);
    topfullTotalPatient = new SimulationDisplays.Patient(_self, View.TopFullTotal, _self.GetPatient('patient'));
    topfullTotalResponder1 = new SimulationDisplays.Responder(_self, View.TopFullTotal, _self.GetResponder('responder1'));
    topfullTotalResponder2 = new SimulationDisplays.Responder(_self, View.TopFullTotal, _self.GetResponder('responder2'));

    //add layers to view
    topFullTotalView = new Simulation.View(View.TopFullTotal, [topfullTotalBackground, topfullTotalBystanders, topfullTotalPatient, topfullTotalResponder1, topfullTotalResponder2]);

    //add view to controller
    _self.ViewController.AddView(topFullTotalView);

    var endTime = new Date().getTime();

}
```

With each view instance being created, a layer gets created and the images will be created in the constructor:

```
    _self.AddImage("Start", new Kinetic.Image(simulation.GetImage("topfullTotal", "patient_start_clothing")));
_self.AddImage("StartNoClothes", new Kinetic.Image(simulation.GetImage("topfullTotal", "patient_start_noClothing")));

_self.AddImage("RecoveryPosition", new Kinetic.Image(simulation.GetImage("topfullTotal", "patient_recoveryPosition")));

// Hitspot Head
_self.AddHitspot("Head", new Kinetic.Image(simulation.GetImage("topfullTotal", "victim_head")));
_self.GetHitspot("Head").on("click", function () {
    simulation.ShowContentMenu("victim_head", _view, _self.GetHitspot("Head"));
    Mouse("default");
});
_self.GetHitspot("Head").on("mouseover", function () {
    Mouse("pointer");
});
_self.GetHitspot("Head").on("mouseout", function () {
    Mouse("default");
});
etc...
```

Now i traced some info about the contruction time:

trace: CreateTopFullTotalView 1018ms
trace: CreateBreathingView 273ms
trace: CreateThoraxView 197ms
trace: CreateNeckLeft 61ms
trace: CreateNeckRight 46ms
trace: CreateWristLeft 49ms
trace: CreateWristRight 50ms
trace: Created all views 1697ms

My profile information from the developer tools in chrome tells me that Kinetic.Shape.drawImage has around 60% of something... (think of the precessor of whatever)?

I also tried to load the images as sprites, does not make any difference.

I'm only half way of the project. So a lot of images will be added in time, i can't have this much latency..

Any halp will be appriciated a lot!

Thanks in advance

Comment: How much of the time is taken by just loading the images? Have you tried preloading the images? Or possibly postloading them by creating blank images then applying the image attribute as the images load? Also, it may work faster if you create a group to push all of your Kinetic objects into, then add the group to the layer once it has completed, instead of adding a group to the layer then adding the objects to the group one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for reading and and  replying. Yes, i do prealod all images at first. When the preloading is done, than i put everything in motion to add the images to the layers. I did not try to put everything in a group first. Gonna try that ASAP :D

Comment: This has been a while. I did chaneg the progress so a group is filled, and than the group is added to the layer, but it didn't had any effect..